# The specified mailbox Identity:username doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

running into a bit of a problem here. First, Powershell is running elevated and connected to EXOL with a global admin account.

If I use 'get-mailbox username' it will return the user mailbox info.

If I try 'get-mailboxfolder -identity usermane:\inbox' or :\calendar, then it comes back with 'The specified mailbox Identity:username doesn't exist.'

I have tried the username in multiple ways including trying the email and the alias. I have tried to find multiple folders using multiple usernames and the only one that returns is mine.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Try getting statistics to verify the folder names : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 0):

This is by design for the [Get-MailboxFolder cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolder?view=exchange-ps).

From the help page:
"Use the Get-MailboxFolder cmdlet to view folders in your own mailbox. Administrators can't use this cmdlet to view folders in other mailboxes."

Comment: Well, guess next time I will RTFM a little closer

Comment: @nosupport2020 As this answers your question please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).